What is the source for performing a levaya for a burnt sefer torah
Unfortunately due to a recent tragic mishap a sefer torah was burnt in a shul fire.
The community is conducting a levaya in similar incidents a levaya was also performed. I understand that sifrei kodesh (holy books) which are burnt should be buried out of respect. I am curious to know if any halachic authorities mention performing a levaya. If not, where did this practice come from?

Orach Chaim 154:5 talks about burying a Seder Torah thats unusable.
